# Get ID of each descendent element of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, svg

How would I get the ID of every descendant of an element in .svg.

I tried:

```
var test = $(svgDoc).find('#main').each(function() {console.log(this.id)});
```

But this only printed main.

EDIT: svgDoc has the element with id = main and I want all the descendents of main, not of svgDoc.

Comment: replace `#main` with `*`

Comment: i hope your #main is an unique element

Comment: You want all descendants of svg element or of #main element? Your question is not so clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the `id` of all descendants of `#main` in svgDoc:

```
$('#main *', svgDoc).each(function() {console.log(this.id)});
```